# PDFBox skipping text

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using Apache pdfbox to read a pdf that was scanned. The order of text sometimes appears jumbled in some of the pdfs. For instance, in the image below, you can notice how a section is completely skipped while selecting text from Adobe Reader for a pdf. The same happens when the pdf is read programmatically using pdfbox. I understand that this is related to pdf structure. But, I was hoping to find answers to the following questions in SO:

1. Why exactly does this happen inside a pdf?
2. How do detect this programmatically in java? What would be potential approaches?
3. What is the fix for this problem? (Apart from reading setting readSorted to true in PDFStripper)

Part of the pdf file is [here](https://gofile.io/d/GMMPMA) for download.
[image]

Comment: Please share the PDF.

Comment: @mkl updated the pdf link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why exactly does this happen inside a pdf?

The contents of a PDF page you see as a final, static image are drawn following a sequence of instructions in its content stream. These instructions mostly either set some property (color, font, ...) or actually draw something ("draw a line from A to B", "draw text string A starting at B", ...). The PDF standard does not require to arrange these instructions in reading order, e.g. the string "Hello world" may be drawn by first drawing "world" and then drawing "Hello" before it.

The PDFBox text stripper by default extracts the text in the order it is drawn. E.g. assume on your page there are four text pieces A, B, C, and D visibly arranged in that order but drawn in the order A, C, D, and B. PDFBox by default will extract them in the latter order, A, C, D, and B. (If you ask it to sort, you'll get it in top-to-bottom, left-to-right order.)

Also Adobe Reader marks text in the order it is drawn. E.g. again assume on your page there are four text pieces A, B, C, and D visibly arranged in that order but drawn in the order A, C, D, and B. If you mark from A to C, B will not be marked, only A and C.

#### For example your PDF

Page 2 of your document is indeed drawn in a funny order:

- The page content stream starts with an instruction to draw the form Xobject named **X0**. You can consider such objects as something like *macros*, independent content streams that can be included in the drawing of other content streams. Thus, the content stream of that form Xobject is drawn now:

  - The Xobject **X0** content stream starts with an instruction to draw an image Xobject. Image Xobjects contain bitmap graphics in a number of formats. The bitmap in question contains the scanned page *except all letters*, i.e. essentially dirt specks and a few lines:

    [image: image xobject]
  - Thereafter there are a lot of text drawing instructions drawing all paragraphs *except paragraph 7 and paragraph 8.01*:

    [image: the whole form Xobject X0]
  - Hereafter the content stream of the form Xobject ends, so execution continues in the page content stream.
- The page content stream continues with text drawing instruction drawing the two missing paragraphs:

  [image: the whole page 2]

This explains your observation:

[image: observation]

The start and end of your marked text are drawn in the form Xobject. Thus, only text in that form Xobject is marked, not the two paragraphs drawn later in the page content stream.

By the way, if you wonder why the text does look like a bitmapped scanned image in spite of being drawn as text... The fonts used here have been constructed from the scanned page by cutting small pieces from it containing what the OCR mechanism considered a single glyph. This sometimes does not exactly correspond to individual characters, some glyphs in that font correspond to multiple characters:

[image: Page 2 font F0 excerpt]

As you see, for some characters there are multiple glyphs in the font (e.g. the lowercase 'o') and there are some glyphs containing multiple characters (e.g. the 'es' or 'mi').

### What is the fix for this problem? (Apart from reading setting readSorted to true in PDFStripper)

Well, you have to decide what you want. Either you want the text in the order it is drawn or you want it in a sorted order.

If you want it in drawing order, there will every once in a while be documents with such erratic jumps in the order of text blocks.

If you want it in a different order, you'll have to sort. The sorting PDFBox offers is a simple top-to-bottom, left-to-right sorting. If you have a different sorting on your mind, you can retrieve the `TextPosition` objects from the text stripper in which it stores glyphs plus their positions, sizes and orientation on the page, and sort them yourself.

### How do detect this programmatically in java? What would be potential approaches?

What exactly do you mean by "this"?

- Do you mean that the text drawing instructions do not draw top-to-bottom, left-to-right?

  For that you can simply override either of the `PDFTextStripper` methods `processTextPosition(TextPosition)` or `writeString(String, List<TextPosition>)` and analyze the positions in the `TextPosition` instances. If they suddenly jump upwards or (on the same line) left, you found such a situation.
- Or do you mean that the text drawing instructions do not draw in reading order?

  This is very difficult, there are multiple situations in which the reading order does jump up again, e.g. in case of multi-column text or inset text boxes. This definitively is beyond a stack overflow answer.

Comment: I think I was able to achieve what I was looking for using the first approach you mentioned. Thank you for your answer. I will reward the bounty in 18hours - looks like it has to wait till then.

Comment: No need to hurry. I had already started answering before you offered the bounty, it was not merely for the bounty. ;)

Comment: your answer deserves the bounty even without the bounty placed :-D - it was that good.